# Blank question pages?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, question-count

While flagging a few posts tonight, I came across the user [raja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51659/raja?tab=stats&qpage=3&qsort=recent).  He has 21 questions?

**But why only one page?**

When I click to page 2 or page 3, it shows only page 1?

Were his questions merged & counts not updated or something?

Comment: Quite interesting.  The mobile site is pretty messed up too, though differently.

Comment: I am also seeing this effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blank page ... what blank page :)

---

Good catch... sorted now.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML source for the [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51659/raja) of the user raja contains this fragment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    StackExchange.ready(function() { StackExchange.user.init({ userid: 51659, accountId:  }); });
</script>
```

which is illegal javascript in that the `accountId` value is missing.  This causes various things to crash when you try to click things on the page.

Here is a Chrome console error:

[image: Error Message]